# Python: Manipulating objects using operator overloading

Tags: python, oop, overloading

I am trying to create a class which contains two floats; One data point and one error associated with that data point.  Here is my class definition:

```
class DataPoint:
def __init__(self, Datum, Error, Operator):
    self.Datum    = Datum
    self.Error    = Error
    self.Operator = Operator
def ReturnDatum(self):
    return self.Datum
def ReturnError(self):
    return self.Error
def ReturnOperator(self):
    return self.Operator
```

The operator field just holds a string and doesn't really matter for my question.
My aim now is to be able to overload the '+' operator so that once I have defined two instances of my class I can simply have an expression like:

```
    Object3 = Object1 + Object2
```

Where Object3 has Datum3 = Datum1 + Datum2, and similarly simple expressions for Error.  I have tried to do this by using the following function definition (inside my class definition):

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return DataPoint(self, self.Datum + other.Datum, math.sqrt(self.Error * self.Error + other.Error * other.Error), 'NULL')
```

But I get errors which basically imply I havent definined my overload correctly.
Thanks in advance
Jack

EDIT: The errors are things of the form

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DataCombination.py", line 78, in <module>
TempObject = LineData[0] - LineData[1]
  File "DataCombination.py", line 22, in __sub__
return DataPoint(self, self.Datum + other.Datum, math.sqrt(self.Error * self.Error + other.Error * other.Error), '+')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'str' and 'str'
```

EDIT2: Small runnable example use code:

```
import math
import sys

# Path to file and filename
FileLocation = 'DataSet.dat'

class DataPoint:
def __init__(self, Datum, Error, Operator):
    self.Datum    = Datum
    self.Error    = Error
    self.Operator = Operator
def __add__(self, other):
    return DataPoint(self.Datum + other.Datum, math.sqrt(self.Error * self.Error + other.Error * other.Error), '+')
def __sub__(self, other):
    return DataPoint(self.Datum - other.Datum, 1.0, 'NULL')
def __mul__(self, other):
    return DataPoint(self.Datum * other.Datum, 1.0, 'NULL')
def __div__(self, other):
    return DataPoint(self.Datum / other.Datum, 1.0, 'NULL')
def ReturnDatum(self):
    return self.Datum
def ReturnError(self):
    return self.Error
def ReturnOperator(self):
    return self.Operator

# Read in the data set from the file
File = open(FileLocation, 'r')
FileSegments = [line.split( ) for line in File.readlines()]

# Clean up the input
for i in xrange(FileSegments.__len__()):
for j in xrange(FileSegments[i].__len__()):
    FileSegments[i][j] = FileSegments[i][j].translate(None, '()')

# Loop over the number lines in the file
for i in xrange(FileSegments.__len__() - 2):

LineData = []

Count = (FileSegments[i].__len__() + 1) / 4

# Import strings into list of objects
for j in xrange((FileSegments[i].__len__() + 1) / 4 - 1):
    x =     j * 4
    y = 2 + j * 4
    z = 3 + j * 4
    LineData.append(DataPoint(FileSegments[i][x], FileSegments[i][y], FileSegments[i][z]))
LineData.append(DataPoint(FileSegments[i][-3], FileSegments[i][-1], 'NULL'))

TempObject = LineData[0] - LineData[1]
```

Where an example DataSet.dat looks like this:

```
(-5.63150902306 +/- 0.549562002684) * (9.62647766508 +/- 1.00395610402) + (16.9559698529 +/- 0.507466944938) + (1.07686005998 +/- 0.713190458948)
(9.40128537128 +/- 0.673031987441) * (7.65561264405 +/- 0.11828791914)
(3.19433075143 +/- 1.16442961316) / (8.49485815486 +/- 0.936343018664)
```

Comment: Please post the errors you got and some input. What are the values for  `self.Datum` and `self.Error`?

Comment: They are just floats, and the error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DataCombination.py", line 78, in <module>
    TempObject = LineData[0] - LineData[1]
  File "DataCombination.py", line 22, in __sub__
    return DataPoint(self, self.Datum - other.Datum, math.sqrt(self.Error * self.Error + other.Error * other.Error), '+')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: please edit the information to your question

Comment: @JackMedley You shouldn't be passing `self` when instantiating a new `DataPoint`

Comment: Please post a runnable example.

Comment: @JanneKarila The above class definition with:

Obj1 = DataPoint(3.4, 0.12, '+')
Obj2 = DataPoint(123.1, 3.56, '/')
Obj3 = Ob1 + Obj2

Comment: @JackMedley - Please create the [smallest complete program that demonstrates the error](http://sscce.org). Then copy-paste that program into your question.

Comment: @Robᵩ please see above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First Bug

Try:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return DataPoint(
        self.Datum + other.Datum, 
        math.sqrt(self.Error * self.Error + other.Error * other.Error), 
        'NULL')
```

Note that you don't have to pass 'self' when you create the new `DataPoint` object.

---

#### Second Bug

You initialize your data with `str`s, but you intend to initialize them with `float`s.

Try:

```
def __init__(self, Datum, Error, Operator):
  self.Datum    = float(Datum)
  self.Error    = float(Error)
  self.Operator = Operator
```

Comment: Though, the error seems to occur before. Otherwise the error should have been `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)`.

Comment: I see, ok I've removed that but I still get the error.  I am wondering if instead of just having 'self.Datum + other.Datum' I should perhaps have 'self.ReturnDatum() + other.ReturnDatum()'

Comment: No, that change should not be required. I don't know why you still get an error. When I make the change, [I don't get the error.](http://ideone.com/ct9wmw). Perhaps you could paste a **complete**, **short** program into your question.

Comment: @JanneKarila - Just noticed your comment. You are exactly correct, the earlier error was the `str`/`float` type mismatch.